# Usage of global.d.ts on submodules upon postInstall script

Tags: typescript, npm

I have an issue using npm postinstall scripts with tsc inside.

I have 2 modules:

- module A that include module B in package.json
- module B, in typescript, with a global.d.ts to handle deps that are un plain JS and a postinstall script `"postinstall": "tsc -p tsconfig-prod.json",`

When I go into module A and run `npm i` the postInstall script of module B fail saying that there are no modules for those that are set in its global.d.ts

If I run `tsc` or `npm i` directly in module B there are no problems.

I tried to copy module B's global.d.ts in module A, but it doesn't solve the bug.

I run out of idea to solve it, any help ? ^^

Comment: Did You tried use latest typescript version ???

Comment: No I didn't, my components are using TS 3.7.2... For this time I solved my problem by rewriting all used sub-modules to TS.

But next time I'll try to upgrade to 3.8.